# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when webscraping image title

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
url2 = 'https://www.newegg.ca/Desktop-Graphics-Cards/SubCategory/ID-48?Tid=7708'

# opening up connection, grabbing page
uclient = ureq(url2)
html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()


# html parsing
page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")

#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

print(containers[0].div.div.a.img["title"])

for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text
    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    print(brand)
    print(product_name)
    print(shipping)
```

The problem occurs during the for loop `brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]`
It gives me the error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. The strange thing is that I can access this title and even print it outside of the loop `print(containers[0].div.div.a.img["title"])` Please help me figure out what is going on here. Thanks, all the best!

Comment: Without having ran the code, my guess is that this problem is happening with an element other than the zeroth one, in other words `containers[i]` for `i != 0`. Check if all the elements in `containers` actually have the "structure" `div.div.a.img["title"]`.

Comment: On which iteration of the loop is that error thrown?

Comment: I used `for number, container in enumerate(containers):  print('---', number, '---') ... ` to see which iteration makes problem and it gives me error for `containers[15]`. You should use `if/else` to check if `container.div.div.a.img` gives `None` and skip this element.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
for number, container in enumerate(containers):  
    print("---", number, "---") 
    # ... code ...
```

I found that it makes problem only for `containers[15]`.

You should use `if/else` to check if `container.div.div.a.img` gives `None` and skip this element or set some default text.

```
    if container.div.div.a.img:
        brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    else:
        brand = "???"
```

---

Full working code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq

url2 = 'https://www.newegg.ca/Desktop-Graphics-Cards/SubCategory/ID-48?Tid=7708'

# opening up connection, grabbing page
uclient = ureq(url2)
html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")

#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item-container"})

#print(containers[15].div.div.a.img["title"])

for number, container in enumerate(containers):
    print("---", number, "---")

    if container.div.div.a.img:
        brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    else:
        brand = "???"

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class": "item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print(brand)
    print(product_name)
    print(shipping)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I check web page to see this `containers[15]` and it has extra `div` with text `#1 BEST SELLER` and this makes problem. It needs different method to get it - ie.

```
    brand = container.div.find("img", {"title": True})["title"]
```

You may use it even with all containers

```py
for number, container in enumerate(containers):
    print("---", number, "---")

    #if container.div.div.a.img:
    #    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    #else:
    #    brand = "???"
        
    brand = container.div.find('img', {"title": True})["title"]
        
    product_name = container.find("a", {"class": "item-title"}).text
    shipping = container.find("li", {"class": "price-ship"}).text.strip()

    print(brand)
    print(product_name)
    print(shipping)
```